# Join on a selected number of digits

Tags: sql, oracle

The column ddm_zip has only 5 digit zipcodes. The column tt_pad_zip contains values anywhere between 2-5. I would like to perform a join selecting values that appear on both sides of the table.

However, tt_pad_zip has various levels of granularity.

For e.g. when we see value of 55 in tt_pad_zip, it is considering all zipcodes that start with 55, for e.g. 551...553...55636 etc. Hence I want the join to select this.

For e.g. when we see value of 558 in tt_pad_zip, it is considering all zipcodes that start with 558, for e.g. 5581...5585...558743 etc. Hence I want the join to select this.

However if there is a value in tt_pad_zip that has the exact zipcode as ddm_zip e.g. 58636 as shown below, I would like the output to pick this .

```
column: ddm_zip       column: tt_pad_zip
55636                 55
57254                 5734
58636                 57254
                      58636
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in the previous question, the join is happening ona  different condition.

Comment: Do you want this join to only return a single row in tt_pad_zip for each row in ddm_zip? Specifically, the row in tt_pad_zip with the longest matching substring?

Comment: @kfinity if in tt_pad_zip we see a zipcode of 55, then we select ALL zips in ddm_zip that starts with 55 eg. 551,5511,55643 etc. If in tt_pad_zip we see a more granular zipcode like 55636, then we join on this and so on. I updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: I was basically asking whether you wanted Radagast81's answer or MT0's answer, ie, do you want to exclude less granular zipcodes when a more granular one exists.

Comment: @kfinity That is correct, I would like to exclude less granular zip codes, when a more granular one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join on the `SUBSTR`ing of `ddm_zip` that has equal length to the `tt_pad_zip` value you are comparing it to. Either:

```
SUBSTR( ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( tt_pad_zip ) ) = tt_pad_zip
```

or:

```
ddm_zip LIKE tt_pad_zip || '%'
```

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( ddm_zip ) AS
SELECT '55636' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '57254' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '55824' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( tt_pad_zip ) AS
SELECT '55'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5734'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '57254' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '55636' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON t1.ddm_zip LIKE t2.tt_pad_zip || '%'
```

**Output**:

```
DDM_ZIP | TT_PAD_ZIP
:------ | :---------
55636   | 55        
55636   | 55636     
57254   | 57254     
55824   | 55
```

**Query 2**: If you want the most granular match.

```
SELECT DDM_ZIP,
       MAX( TT_PAD_ZIP ) AS TT_PAD_ZIP
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON t1.ddm_zip LIKE t2.tt_pad_zip || '%'
GROUP BY DDM_ZIP
```

**Output**:

```
DDM_ZIP | TT_PAD_ZIP
:------ | :---------
55636   | 55636     
57254   | 57254     
55824   | 55
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2e36ee9cf2b91a40abf905749eb73ac)*

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
-- Sample Data:
WITH dat (ddm_zip, tt_pad_zip) AS 
  (SELECT 0,55 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1,5734 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
     SELECT 2,57254 FROM dual
    UNION ALL  
     SELECT 3,55636 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
     SELECT 55636, 99 FROM dual
    UNION ALL  
     SELECT 57254, 88 FROM dual
    UNION ALL  
     SELECT 57341, 77 FROM dual)
-- Query:
SELECT d2.ddm_zip, d1.tt_pad_zip 
  FROM dat d1
  JOIN dat d2 
   -- Join the data via like:
    ON d2.ddm_zip LIKE d1.tt_pad_zip || '%'
   -- Exclude the data where a "better" match exists:
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dat d3
                    WHERE d2.ddm_zip LIKE d3.tt_pad_zip || '%'
                      AND LENGTH(d1.tt_pad_zip) < LENGTH(d3.tt_pad_zip))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional join with a CASE statement in the ON clause:

```
select t1.ddm_zip, t2.tt_pad_zip
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.ddm_zip like case 
  when exists(select 1 from table2 where tt_pad_zip = t1.ddm_zip) then t2.tt_pad_zip  
  else '%' || t2.tt_pad_zip || '%'
end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=50ffca374c1f8b06180df060679d61c6).
Results:

```
> DDM_ZIP | TT_PAD_ZIP
> :------ | :---------
> 55636   | 55        
> 57254   | 57254     
> 58636   | 58636
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `SUBSTR` operation to just compare the first two numbers of each column. I don't know which type of join you want, your table names, or example data, but here is a good syntax.

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON SUBSTR(ddm_zip, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(tt_pad_zip, 1,2)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm